# Solving a matrix equation with overdetermined case

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

I have a matrix equation $\begin{bmatrix}
        a& e& i\\
        b & f & j\\
        c & g &k\\
        d & h& l\end{bmatrix}.B=\begin{bmatrix}
       d& c&i\\
g&e&f\\
a&f&h\\
b&k&l\end{bmatrix}$, Here $B$ is $3\times 3$ matrix. This becomes an overdetermined systems. Is there any solution, and if not what conditions can be imposed on the matrix entries for the solution to exist.

Comment: Is $B$ a known, matrix with numerical entries ?

Comment: Have a look at pseudo inverse

Comment: $B$ is the transformation matrix that i need to calculate,it is unknown